# Why can i not see the camera rectangle?

Tags: camera

[image: the second screen to appear when camera button toggled]I am new to blender and i am watching a tutorial for the basics, but in the tutorial, when he uses the camera there is a rectangle apparent in the image (see attached photos) but for mine i do not have that? Pleasehelp, it would be much appreciated.

i do have the default settings, and my numbed is working. also i definitely have a camera.[[image: the first screen to appear when camera button toggledthe second screen to appear when camera button toggled again] [image: tutorial camera view]

Comment: Scroll your mouse. You're just zoomed in and the camera borders are outside your view.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want your view look exactly like this? You have to press 0 on your Numpad to go to camera view. If you want it to have orange outline, then you need to select your camera... If you want to see render only in camera view, then you have to check these 2 option:

[image]

But what you see that guy on youtube doing is simply pressing 0 on his numpad.

Or as moonboots says, maybe you don't have a camera in your scene. Sharing your screen or file could help.

Comment: Yes, but when i press 0 on my numbed it doesn't do that? Im confused.

Comment: Are you using default settings? Maybe you somehow changed settings, your numpad is working right?

Comment: maybe you don't have any camera and you need to create one?

Comment: There's a camera in the outliner and the cross hairs are a camera overlay.  The 3D viewport is just zoomed in far enough that the camera frame is outside the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem, I solved it by pressing the view drop down menu on the top left-hand corner - camera - set active object as camera. and it did its thing.
[image: dropdownmenu]